# How to use gitlab runner correctly?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I try to figure out how to deploy a project with gitlab ci-cd pipelines.
I created a runner, registered him on the remote server. After that, I am trying to implement a simple script in the .yml:

```
 - whoami
 - echo "123" > 123.txt
```

In the job info, I see that `whoami` out to me wrong user (root instead ubuntu), and also file isn't created.

More of then - how does the repository know that I want to use exactly that runner I created? I can't find any information about it. As I understand I have to bind my repository with my runner, in another way.....all repositories will use the same runner!

Answer (score 1):

In gitlab, you should be able to attach runners in 2 ways to a project;
either you register a runners specific to the project or you enable shared runners (you should be able to see the list of both categories under project setting > CICD > Runners)

If you don't see any available runners in there, you may be configuring the runners wrong.

To select a specific runner, you can use the 'tag' of the runner.

you can either set a default for the pipeline and have stage specifc too.

here is how you would do for default

```
 default:
  tags:
    - backend-runner
```

Comment: Do I wrong? - on my mind, the runner executes pipeline scripts, which run on the server where the runner is registered. So, if I will create script `echo "123" > 123.txt`, the appropriate file will have appeared on the server where gitlab runner was registered. Right?

Comment: Hey Valentyn; I might not have understood your setup correctly; is your gitlab sever self hosted or are you using gitlab online

Comment: I use gilab "online". If you mean https://gitlab.com